# google maps api polygon listener toggling

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

So I have two layers of polygons on my map. These polygons are zoom level dependent.

When I zoom in I would like to hide the first level polygons (or remove their listeners and make them transparent), and when I zoom out I need to  hide level 2 polygons and show the first level of polygons.

My current strategy is to make the polygons initially transparent, and the listeners will make them opaque when necessary. To achieve my polygon toggling, I would add and remove listeners when the zoom changes.

So I have an array of level1 polygons and an array of level2 polygons but I can't seem to toggle them.

How come this doesn't work? Shouldn't addListener do the exact opposite as removeListener?

```
function zoomedout(map) {

$.each(level2Listeners, function(k,v) {
   google.maps.event.removeListener(v);
});



$.each(level1Listeners, function(k,v) {
   google.maps.event.addListener(v);
});
```

}

Is there any other more reasonable strategy to achieve the toggling?

Comment: You're thinking about this in the wrong way. Instead of adding and removing listeners, consider having one permanently attached 'zoom_changed' listener which, when it fires, shows/hides layers, depending on the new zoom level. Get this straight in your mind and the code should be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to implement your layers is to iterate through the arrays in a map zoom_changed listener, setting the "map" property of the polygons appropriately.  The code below assumes your google.maps.Map object is "map" and global (or at least available in the scope of the listener).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function() {
  if (map.getZoom() > zoomThreshold) {
      for (var i = 0; i<level1polys.length; i++) {
         // hide the level1 polygons
         if (level1polys[i].getMap() != null) level1polys[i].setMap(null);
      }
      for (var i=0; i<level2polys.length; i++) {
         // show the level2 polygons
         if (level2polys[i].getMap() == null) level2polys[i].setMap(map);
      }
  else {
      for (var i = 0; i<level1polys.length; i++) {
         // show the level1 polygons
         if (level1polys[i].getMap() == null) level1polys[i].setMap(map);
      }
      for (var i=0; i<level2polys.length; i++) {
         // hide the level2 polygons
         if (level2polys[i].getMap() != null) level2polys[i].setMap(null);
      }
  }
});
```

You may want to add state so you don't have to process through all the polygons for each change of zoom level only doing that if the zoom changes across the threshold.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked for another reasonable approach, I had a similar task some month's ago (toggle about 5000 overlays depending on the zoom) and came across another solution.

A Polygon is a [`MVCObject`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MVCObject), you can bind a property  of a MVCObject to the property of another MVCObject.

I've created new properties for the Map-Instance(which also is an MVCObject), and updated these properties on the zoom_changed-event.

The workflow:

1. set the properties on zoom_changed

   ---

   ```
   google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed',function(){

      var z=this.getZoom();

       //set map.prop1 to Map-instance when zoom<=5,otherwise to null
      var p1=(z<=5)?this:null;if(this.get('prop1')!==p1){this.set('prop1',p1);}

       //set map.prop2 to Map-instance when zoom>5,otherwise to null
      var p2=(z>5)?this:null;if(this.get('prop2')!==p2){this.set('prop2',p2);}
   });
   ```
2. bind the map-property of the overlay to the desired property:

   ---

   ```
   //this polygon will only be displayed at a zoom up to 5
   somePolygon.bindTo('map',map,'prop1');
   ```
3. trigger the `zoom_changed`-event to initialize the properties:

   ---

   ```
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'zoom_changed');
   ```

A simple demo with 4 circles: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/FPvLx/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/FPvLx/)